# Laravel morph belongs to?

Tags: laravel, polymorphism

I've got a situation where multiple tables have a `belongsTo` relationship to a category table in `laravel 5.4`.

So I thought about this structure:

**User** table:

```
id
name
email
category_id   <--
```

**Category table**

```
id
model_type
name
```

Is this possible with a `morph` relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would not be since `model_type` is just a constraint of which categories are available for which models.  If you set it up like that you would add that constraint on each model's relation like:

```
class User extends Model
{
    // User class

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class)->where('model_type', '=', static::class);
    }
}
```

Or since you have many models that belong to `Category` you could take that one step further and use a trait for the relation and place the trait on each model that belongs to `Category`:

```
trait BelongsToCategory()
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class)->where('model_type', '=', static::class);
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    use BelongsToCategory;

    // User class
}
```